# d3js - d3.scale.category10() not working?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I add `d3js` to my new project:

and do a simple test just to make sure it works:

```
d3.select(".d3div").transition()
    .duration(750)
    .style("background-color", "black");
```

this work. However:

```
var colors = d3.scale.category10().domain([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
```

this give error:

> myd3.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'category10' of
>   undefined

and I try some other function too:

```
d3.scale.linear()
```

have some errors:

> myd3.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of
>   undefined

if I change the import to

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
```

then it works for the functions, but the `transition` animation not working anymore.

I want to use the latest version. but it seems like there are scope changes that I am not aware of.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is no more `d3.scale.category` in D3 v4.x.

According to the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md), here are the changes:

```
d3.scale.category10 ↦ d3.schemeCategory10
d3.scale.category20 ↦ d3.schemeCategory20
d3.scale.category20b ↦ d3.schemeCategory20b
d3.scale.category20c ↦ d3.schemeCategory20c
```

These are color schemes that...

> ... are designed to work with d3.scaleOrdinal.

So, instead of `d3.scale.category10()`, you'll have to use:

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

Here is the documentation for the category scales: https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#schemeCategory10

PS: You don't need to set the domain for an ordinal scale like this. Check this demo:

```js
var data = d3.range(10);

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var circles = svg.selectAll(".circles")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("circle")
 .attr("cx", d=>10+d*25)
 .attr("cy", 50)
 .attr("r", 10)
 .attr("fill", d=>color(d));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this notation of " d=>10+d*25 "  ? is it some sort of short hand notation to anonymous function ?

Comment: No, this is an arrow function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 2):

In d3v4, you need to use [`d3.schemeCatgory`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#schemeCategory10):

```
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

Answer (score 0):

if someone using angular 2

```
 var colorScale=d3Scale.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

this is the correct way.