# Adding node labels to D3 Network

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, d3-force-directed

I can't figure out how to add node labels to my D3 force-directed network. This code gets the labels to show up but they won't move with the network.

How can I append the text to the node itself? Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks a bunch.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.links line {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: .6;
    shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}

.nodes circle {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
    pointer-events: none;
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

#tools div {
    display: inline;
}

form,
select {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id='tools'></div>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height");

    var graph; //Global variable for the graph

    svg.append('rect')
        .attr('width', '100%')
        .attr('height', '100%')
        .attr('fill', '#FFFFFF');

    // Call zoom for svg container.
    svg.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', zoomed)).on("dblclick.zoom", null);
    var container = svg.append('g');
    //Create scales for color and edge weight

    var color = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([1776, 2017])
        .range([0.1, 1]);

    var weight = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 1])
        .range([1, 5]);

    // Create form for search (see function below).
    var search = d3.select("div#tools").append('form').attr('onsubmit', 'return false;');
    var box = search.append('input')
        .attr('type', 'text')
        .attr('id', 'searchTerm')
        .attr('placeholder', 'Type to search...');
    var button = search.append('input')
        .attr('type', 'button')
        .attr('value', 'Search')
        .on('click', function() {
            searchNodes();
        });

    //Toggle for ego networks on click (function below).
    var toggle = 0;

    //Create groups for nodes and links
    var link = container.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll(".link"),
        node = container.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll(".node");


    //Get data from json file, assign that data to graph variable.
    d3.json("semantic_great_nouns.json", function(error, json) {
        if (error) throw error;
        graph = json;
        update();
    });

    // Zooming function translates the size of the svg container.
    function zoomed() {
        container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.transform.x + ", " + d3.event.transform.y + ") scale(" + d3.event.transform.k + ")");
    }
    // Search for nodes by making all unmatched nodes temporarily transparent.
    function searchNodes() {
        var term = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
        var selected = container.selectAll('.node').filter(function(d, i) {
            return d.id.toString().search(term.toLowerCase()) == -1;
        });
        selected.style('opacity', '0');
        var link = container.selectAll('.link');
        link.style('stroke-opacity', '0');
        d3.selectAll('.node').transition()
            .duration(20000)
            .style('opacity', '1');
        d3.selectAll('.link').transition().duration(20000).style('stroke-opacity', '1');
    }
    //Draw the graph!
    function update() {
        //Parameters for force layout simulation
        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(graph.nodes)
            .force("link", d3.forceLink(graph.links)) //.id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength([-300])) //.distanceMax([500]))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("x", d3.forceX())
            .force("y", d3.forceY())
            .stop();
        //The graph will be drawn behind the scenes and then displayed in static form.
        //This code tells the program how many times to iterate through the layout simulation.
        for (var i = 0, n = Math.ceil(Math.log(simulation.alphaMin()) / Math.log(1 - simulation.alphaDecay())); i < n; ++i) {
            simulation.tick();
        }
        // Data join with links and corresponding nodes.
        //If we wanted to reload the graph with an adjusted node set, we could do so.
        link = link.data(graph.links, function(d) {
            return d.source.id + ', ' + d.target.id;
        });
        link.exit().remove();
        var linkEnter = link.enter().append('line')
            .attr('class', 'link');
        link = linkEnter.merge(link)
            .attr("x1", function(d) {
                return d.source.x;
            })
            .attr("y1", function(d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr("x2", function(d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })
            .attr("y2", function(d) {
                return d.target.y;
            })
            .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
                return weight(d.weight);
            });

        // When adding and removing graph.nodes, reassert attributes and behaviors.
        node = node.data(graph.nodes, function(d) {
            return d.id;
        });
        node.exit().remove();
        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('circle')
            .attr('r', 20)
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                if (d.bipartite == 1) {
                    return '#103def';
                } else {
                    return '#ed1d0e';
                }
            })
            //color bipartite nodes
            .attr('class', 'node')
            .attr('id', function(d) {
                return "n" + d.id.toString();
            })
            .attr('clickToggle', 0)
            .attr("cx", function(d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return d.y;
            })
            // On click, toggle ego networks for the selected node. (See function below.)
            .on('click', function(d) {
                toggleClick(d);
            });
        node = nodeEnter.merge(node);

        //node.append("label")
        //.attr("dx", 12)
        //.attr("dy", ".35em")
        //.text(function(d) { return d.id });

        var label = svg.append("g").attr("class", "labels").selectAll("g")
            .data(graph.nodes)
            .enter().append("g");

        label.append("text")
            .attr("x", 14)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .style("font-size", "0.7em")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.id;
            })
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return d.y;
            });

        // node.append("text")
        //   .attr("dx", 12)
        // .attr("dy", ".35em")
        //.text(function(d) { return d.id });

        // simulation.on("tick", function () {
        //   link.attr("x1", function (d) {return d.source.x;})
        //     .attr("y1", function (d) {return d.source.y;})
        //   .attr("x2", function (d) {return d.target.x;})
        // .attr("y2", function (d) {return d.target.y;});"""

        //node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
        // });
        //d3.selectAll("circle").attr("cx", function (d) {return d.x;})
        //  .attr("cy", function (d) {return d.y;});
        //d3.selectAll("text").attr("x", function (d) {return d.x;})
        //  .attr("y", function (d) {return d.y;});
        //});
        //node.append("title")
        //.text(function(d) { return d.id; });
    }


    // A function to handle click toggling based on neighboring nodes.
    function toggleClick(d) {
        // Make object of all neighboring nodes.
        connectedNodes = {};
        connectedNodes[d.id] = true;
        graph.links.forEach(function(l) {
            if (l.source.id == d.id) {
                connectedNodes[l.target.id] = true;
            } else if (l.target.id == d.id) {
                connectedNodes[l.source.id] = true;
            };
        });
        if (toggle == 0) {
            // Ternary operator restyles links and nodes if they are adjacent.
            d3.selectAll('.link').style('stroke-opacity', function(l) {
                return l.target == d || l.source == d ? 1 : 0.2;
            });
            d3.selectAll('.node').style('opacity', function(n) {
                if (n.id in connectedNodes) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0.2;
                };
            });
            // Show information when node is clicked
            d3.select('div#tools').append('span').text(d.date);
            toggle = 1;
        } else {
            // Restore nodes and links to normal opacity.
            d3.selectAll('.link').style('stroke-opacity', 0.6);
            d3.selectAll('.node').style('opacity', 1);
            d3.selectAll('span').remove();
            toggle = 0;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot to paste the two more important parts of your code: the simulation and the tick function.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Sorry! Thanks for pointing that out. I added the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link: http://codepen.io/rafszul/pen/KeAaG/

it might help you.

try replacing `"circle" by "rect"` in **JS, CSS** section.

also replace this snippet into JS code to specify width and height of rectangle:

```
var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("rect")

    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", 15)
    .attr("height", 15)
    .call(force.drag);
```

Comment: Anyone visiting this answer using d3 version 4 then check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41178208/14457833) for some changes